# Unexpected results from scipy.integrate.ode integrator dopri5 (Python)

Tags: python, scipy, ode, numerical-integration

I have a Python script like this:

```
def dY_dt(t, Y):
     STUFF (defines the dY_dt values)
     
     if dY6_dt < 0.:
          print("stuff about current parameters")
          1/0 #never fails here
     else:
          pass    

     return [dY1_dt, dY2_dt, dY3_dt, dY4_dt, dY5_dt, dY6_dt]

delta_t = 0.01
t_arr = []
Y_arr = []
t_i = 0.00
Y_i = [Y1_i, Y2_i, Y3_i, Y4_i, Y5_i, Y6_i]
t_arr.append(t_i)
Y_arr.append(Y_i)
t_end = 1000.

backend = 'dopri5'
solver = ode(dY_dt).set_integrator(backend)
solver.set_initial_value(Y_i, t_i)

while solver.successful() and (solver.t+delta_t) <= t_end:
     solver.integrate(solver.t+delta_t)

     #this stuff is used for another purpose
     #dY6dt_total is the change in Y6 after a full time-step of delta_t
     step_num = int((round(solver.t, 4) - delta_t)/delta_t)
     Y6_prev = Y_arr[step_num][5]
     Y6_new = solver.y[5]
     dY6dt_total = Y6_new - Y6_prev 
     

     if dY6dt_total < 0.: #ought to never be the case
          print("stuff about parameters at this time")
          Y6_arr = []
          for i in np.arange(len(Y_arr)):
               Y6_temp = Y_arr[i][5]
               Y6_arr.append(Y6_temp)

          Y6_arr.append(solver.y[5])
          t_arr.append(solver.t)
          plt.plot(t_arr, Y6_arr) #to confirm visually what's happening
          1/0
     else:
          pass 
                   
     STUFF (saving some other parameters into arrays & the such)
     
     t_arr.append(solver.t)
     Y_arr.append(solver.y)

STUFF (saving/outputting arrays & dictionaries)
```

In this case, `dY2_dt <= 0`, for all time, `dY5_dt <= 0`, for all time, and, more importantly, `dY6_dt >= 0`, for all time.

The other three ODE's can be either positive, negative, or, zero. All six ODE's are indirectly coupled to each other in some fashion.

Running this code, over a large variety of parameter spaces and initial conditions, I've found that a subset of my script runs hit the manually inserted error given by `dY6dt_total < 0`.

Given that `dY6_dt >= 0`, for all time, it ought to be the case that `dY6dt_total >= 0`, for all time.

It is unclear to me why after a full time-step of `delta_t = 0.01`, that `dY6dt_total` can be negative. This is for a physical system, and, this happens to correspond to a negative length, which, is non-physical.

The integrator makes a bunch of sub-steps from "t" to "t + delta_t", and for one crash of the code, the crash occurs after the time-step from `t = 84.01` to `t = 84.02`. All of the values of `dY6_dt` during each of these sub-steps are positive, as they should be, but, that suggests the integrator isn't behaving as I would expect (rather than an error in defining `dY6_dt`, causing it to be negative).

Here are those values:

```
t = 84.01
Y6 = 20160.4702157939
dY6_daddet = 2.499582626169507e-05

t = 84.012
Y6 = 20160.470215843894
dY6_dt = 3.1744418995557098

t = 84.013
Y6 = 20160.47735830693
dY6_dt = 2.8810884888089463e-05

t = 84.018
Y6 = 20160.35170456511
dY6_dt = 0.0011118447521629496

t = 84.0188889
Y6 = 20160.10211440677
dY6_dt = 3.2265511820351254

t = 84.02
Y6 = 20160.11990354711
dY6_dt = 3.2239658437410013

t = 84.02
Y6 = 20160.4640434123
dY6_dt = 3.1749812457108955
```

But, after the integration for this time-step:

```
dY6dt_total = -0.006172381603391841
```

Running this script with the same parameters and initial conditions, but, with `delta_t = 0.001`, and, `delta_t = 0.0001`, did not prevent `dY6dt_total < 0`. from occurring around t ~ 80-90, it just changed the exact time it occurred.

Can anyone help with this? Is there something I've misunderstood about how 'dopri5' works? I cannot see how if `dY6_dt >= 0`. for all time, that after a time-step the value of `Y6` decreases.

Comment: The only point that could be critical from the exposed code is the computation of the index. Due to accumulationg rounding errors, the times are not absolutely exactly multiples of the time step. Check if you get better results with `step_num = int(0.1+(solver.t - delta_t)/delta_t)` or just take the last array element, `Y6_prev = Y_arr[-1][5]`.

Comment: Hi Lutz, I actually did that but neglected to show, and, when dY6_dt < 0, I gather all of the previous Y6 values into an array and plot them against time, which confirms that Y6 did indeed decrease in the last time-step leading up to the crash.

Comment: Have now added this to the above code

Comment: Ah, thank you very much gboffi (and @Lutz Lehmann )